# MySql :: select into

Tags: mysql, select

What is the difference between **`:=`** and **`Into`** in the `select` query ?

eg:

```
SELECT  filesinfo.IsFolder, 
        filesinfo.ReferenceID 
INTO    @IsFolder, @ReferenceID 
FROM filesinfo 
WHERE filesinfo.FileID = @ChildID;
```

and:

```
SELECT  @IsFolder := filesinfo.IsFolder,
        @ReferenceID := filesinfo.ReferenceID 
FROM filesinfo 
WHERE filesinfo.FileID = @ChildID;
```

Comment: `:=` is an assignment operator used to assign user variables used in statements

Comment: I notice that when using ':='  the result of query is appeared, but when using 'into' the result is transferred to the variables without appearing in the query result. does that valid ?

Comment: @RaedAlsaleh from that point ... SELECT INTO has no resultset :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `INTO` clause to write the output to a file as well as store in a variable.

While, the assignment operator `:=` only assigns a **scalar** value to a variable.

Answer (score 0):

The main difference is, that `SELECT column INTO @Foo FROM table` should target only one row, otherwise you will get an error. To avoid this you like to use `LIMIT 1`.

(btw you won't get a resultset)

Using `SELECT @Foo := column FROM table` will assign the value from the **last** row.
(it will assign the values from all rows, but at the end it is the value from the last row)

Answer (score 0):

In terms of functionality, they are the same four your example if the query is returning one row. But using

```
SELECT  @IsFolder := filesinfo.IsFolder,
        @ReferenceID := filesinfo.ReferenceID 
FROM filesinfo 
WHERE filesinfo.FileID = @ChildID;
```

has a side effect of outputting the results for the variable assignments while the one with `SELECT .. INTO` does not.

Also note that [`INTO`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select-into.html) has more use cases than just selecting column variables into variables.